# How do I sort a hash with the highest specific value?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash, enums

I have hashes inside an array nammed `elem`, and I must get the "type" keys which have the highest "count" value.

I know that Enumerators are a great thing to know, but I don't understand them very well.

```
elem = [{"type"=>"dododo", "count"=>0, "name"=>"dododo's", "tip"=>"dododo's Level"},
  {"type"=>"dadada", "count"=>1203, "name"=>"dadada's", "tip"=>"dadada's Degree"},
  {"type"=>"dedede", "count"=>717, "name"=>"dedede's", "tip"=>"dedede's Degree"},
  {"type"=>"dididi", "count"=>6, "name"=>"dididi's", "tip"=>"dididi or Professional Degree"}]
```

I'm trying this:

```
elem.each do |i|
  i.each_with_index do |k,v|
    puts v["count"]
  end
end
```

but I know I've missed some step.

I know that these kind of "manoeuvre" are fairly comon and important to know.

Comment: You may want to edit the title, for the record, as you are not sorting, much less sorting a hash.  Maybe something like, "How do I extract a particular hash value from an array of hashes?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to use [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by)

```
elem = [
  {"type"=>"dododo", "count"=>0, "name"=>"dododo's", "tip"=>"dododo's Level"},
  {"type"=>"dadada", "count"=>1203, "name"=>"dadada's", "tip"=>"dadada's Degree"},
  {"type"=>"dedede", "count"=>717, "name"=>"dedede's", "tip"=>"dedede's Degree"},
  {"type"=>"dididi", "count"=>6, "name"=>"dididi's", "tip"=>"dididi or Professional Degree"}
]

max_elem = elem.max_by {|e| e['count']}
puts max_elem['type']
# returns dadada
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @infused ! thanks for the fast response :)